# How to correct Inverse Sum calculation using DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to calculate inverse sum something similar to [https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Quick-Measures-Gallery/Inverse-Aggregator/m-p/342266#M91.](http://I%20am%20trying%20to%20calculate%20inverse%20sum%20similar%20to%20https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Quick-Measures-Gallery/Inverse-Aggregator/m-p/342266#M91.%20%20Power%20Query%20for%20Sample%20Data.)

Power Query for Sample Data.

```
let
Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("nZI/C8IwEMW/imTucPlXXRMrOgYcSweRDl1a0Pr97V3BoTmawyGPBPLjvbxc2yoDBqBWlQq4UO7T5/XsD3rZNv17HsbHPEwjnbWBRa0H1VVbNEpQz6JnCXraomgYRYE1MGgpsLEOlUNjMbDz2BPLNhJbx6KXfdRZbPi/t+LNmjW97qOeXI8seiu4Av1rhibBTOAMcjUlksJzVzhvaoVFzllXgYYipAIMv9jdFw==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Period = _t, Platform = _t, #"Scenarion Name" = _t, #"Source Name" = _t, #"Destination Name" = _t, #"Historical Cases" = _t, #"Scenario Cases" = _t]),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Period", Int64.Type}, {"Platform", type text}, {"Scenarion Name", type text}, {"Source Name", type text}, {"Destination Name", type text}, {"Historical Cases", Int64.Type}, {"Scenario Cases", Int64.Type}}) in #"Changed Type"
```

Problem statement is, when I select a scenario what ever the platforms got filtered for the selected scenario based on different source and destination, it should exclude those platforms and give total sum of history cases of other platforms.

I tried the below DAX

```
_InverseSum = CALCULATE(
SUM('Table'[Historical Cases]), 
FILTER(
    ALL('Table'),
    'Table'[Platform] 
    IN EXCEPT(ALL('Table'[Platform]),
    VALUES('Table'[Platform])) 
    ))
```

but the problem here is.

I have to show that Inverse Sum values in table visual by including Platform, Source, Dest, and period as below image.

Now when i don't have Source, Dest, Platform in my table visual and I keep only Period and Inverse Sum I am getting the right values.

[image]

The total value of history cases for NON A, BP platform is 3155.

It should be same even though I keep other columns like source, dest, platform, scenario, because it should exclude these filtering criteria and give the total sum.

Comment: Just add your sample data with your desired output from them with small explanation.

Comment: I gave the power query to generate sample data @mk